# This transaction should be completed with a commit call

Tags: java, android

I have this code to change fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);

if (isBackable) fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Android studio warn:

**This transaction should be completed with a commit() call**

I don't know how the correct way to solve this warning.

Comment: It is already there, so no problem.

Comment: Yes, it's still working despite the warning. It's just i'm curious because Android Studio keep on warning me. Is it a bad coding or are there some other way to do this?

Comment: This is anroid studio compilation, it thoughts that if we write `beginTransaction()` then in that statement there should be `commit()`;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a false positive.

Android Lint only sees you have chained some fragment transaction calls together without a commit but fails to see the commit on a later row.

You can either

1. ignore the warning,
2. suppress it with `@SuppressLint("CommitTransaction")`, or
3. remove the method chaining i.e. replace

   ```
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
               .beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);
   ```

   with

   ```
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
               .beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

i think if you try this the warn will dispear

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);

if (isBackable) {
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

or

```
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);

    if (isBackable) fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

or

> you could just suppress the warning

good luck !

Comment: I've tried both of it. It's still give the same warning. Of course i could just suppress the warning. Thank you ;)